# Big Oh Notation Prove O(2^n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am revising my old algorithm analysis notes for an interview,

i noticed a question that i was not able to figure out when i was studying

**prove that `2n+10 + n = O(2n)`**

any help would be great!

Comment: Hint: (1) 2^(n+10) = 1024 × 2^n. (2) 2^n + n ≤ 2^(n+1) for all n>=1.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
f(n) ∈ O(g(n))      ⇔      lim supn → ∞ |f(n) / g(n)| < ∞
```

This leads you to

```
lim supn → ∞ |(2n+10 + n) / (2n)| = lim n → ∞ |(210 ⋅ 2n + n) / (2n)|
                                 = lim n → ∞ |(210 ⋅ 2n) / (2n) + (n) / (2n)|
                                 = 210 < ∞
```

In fact you can also prove `2n ∈ O(2n+10 + n)` the same way and you get `2n+10 + n ∈ Θ(2n)`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the definition of Big-Oh notation to solve this problem as shown below:

[image: expression]